# Why Justices abbreviated JJ?

Tags: etymology, legalese

What's reason for second J?  Why not Js or J's?

[Acronyms and initialisms in legal writing - ICLR](https://www.iclr.co.uk/knowledge/glossary/acronyms-and-initialisms-in-legal-writing/)

> **JJ** – Justices (plural, after listing their surnames)

[Difference between: J, JJ, JJA, AJ... etc ? Judge v Justice? : auslaw](https://old.reddit.com/r/auslaw/comments/4d3kex/difference_between_j_jj_jja_aj_etc_judge_v_justice/)

> The Australian Guide to Legal Citation lists the following:
>
> - JJ - Justices

[1.1.6 Naming parliamentarians, courts and judges](https://www.lawfoundation.org.nz/style-guide2018/chapter-pt.1.1.6.html)

> two or more Justices (JJ), for example “O’Regan and Ellen France JJ” or “O’Regan and Ellen France JJ’s concurring opinion …”; and

Answer (score 1):

Justice is abbreviated “J”. “JJ” is plural, because there is more than one J.

Comment: A similar abbreviation is *pp* for *pages*.

Comment: Also *ll* for lines, *qq* for questions, *ss* for saints, *vv* for verses.